# Is this a memory leak ? Fetch JS

Tags: javascript, memory, memory-leaks, async-await, fetch

I'm working on a browser app which runs 24/7.

I have some memory leak issues, so I tried to test everything.

Here I want to test **FETCH**

Here my JS

```
var app = {
    init: function () {
        app.timer = setInterval(app.getData, 500)
    },

    getData: async function () {
        app.response = await fetch("data.php",{ cache: "no-cache" });
        if (app.response.ok) {
            app.text = await app.response.text();
        }
    }
}
app.init();
```

Here data.php :

```
<?php 

$filename = 'data.txt';

if (file_exists($filename)) {
    $content = file_get_contents ($filename);
    echo $content;
}
```

data.txt is just some 010101010101010... text.

I have an increase of **JS Heap** when I record it with "*Performance*" dev tools :
[image]
If I zoom :
[image]

But with the Task Manager from chrome : Seems great increase of Memory footprint and but stable JS Memory

[image]
And with the memory allocation, there is no leak :

[image]

So, based on these results: Could we run this 24/7 with no problems, or will this crash on chromium ?

EDIT: Even with small or big file it increase, with small file it's just slower.

Comment: what is the size of data.txt loaded in memory ? and if it big you can try to work with it in batches

Comment: In my project, it's a very small one there is just 0 or 1. But I'm also interested if it's a big one.

Comment: in your project! is the file injected from somewhere else ?

Comment: The file is just change by a python script

Comment: can you try with one with actual data? and see if the problem from this file

Comment: I try also with a small file, memory footprint increase slowly but continuously.... 
but after a certain period of time it come back down... I have to monitor it longer to see if this really increase or not

Comment: can you stop the timer and try to debug on a single request only?, I sea you have interval that is making a request every 0.5 sec

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219203/discussion-between-lexagc-and-abdelrahman-hussien).